# Is there a Excel function to map multiple data sets to the same date set

Tags: excel-formula

I'm setting up a way to map multiple columns to one date column. My raw data comes by mapping the float number dates (as that's the format they come in).

```
Date, Apple, Date, Microsoft, Date, Google    
43545.66667, 10, 43552.66667, 76, 43544.66667, 4445    
43546.66667, 11, 43553.66667, 78, 43545.66667, 4400    
43549.66667, 12, 43556.66667, 85, 43546.66667, 4403    
43550.66667, 12, 43557.66667, 63, 43549.66667, 4458    
43551.66667, 11,,, 43550.66667, 4875    
43552.66667, 12,,, 43551.66667, 4235    
43553.66667, 12,,, 43552.66667, 4355    
43556.66667, 11,,, 43553.66667, 4442    
43557.66667, 14,,, 43556.66667, 3897    
,,,,43557.66667,4532
```

As you can see, they all have different time periods, however all will have common dates that don't align in a row format. I am wondering if there is some version of a VLOOKUP (best to my knowledge) that will allow me too format it as such (leaving blank any not filled)

```
Date, Apple, Microsoft, Google    
43544.66667, , , , 4445    
43545.66667, 10, , , 4400    
43546.66667, 11, , , 4403    
43549.66667, 12, , , 4458    
43550.66667, 12, , , 4875    
43551.66667, 11, , , 4235    
43552.66667, 12, 76, 4355    
43553.66667, 12, 78, 4442    
43556.66667, 11, 85, 3897    
43557.66667, 14, 63, 4532
```

Comment: Should the time be ignored?

Comment: The time can be ignored, but the problem is that is how it around be received. So I am happy to ignore the time, however it needs to still pull the same results

Comment: If you want excel to pull the unique date/times you will want vba.  If you can provide the date/time list then yes a simple VLOOKUP will return the correct numbers in the other columns.

Comment: Okay, let’s say I only want to match the interference (this will give time the date I believe) however the list comes in a decimal format. Is there a way to map it? I am hoping for either a draggable excel formula or a relatively simple macro, however I’m just starting out and struggling to put this down in code

Comment: Btw, all the times are the same (should all be .666666...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can do your own list of dates/times then put this in the first output cell and drag over and down:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($J2,INDEX($A:$F,0,(COLUMN(A:A)-1)*2+1):INDEX($A:$F,0,(COLUMN(A:A)-1)*2+2),2,FALSE),"")
```

Make sure to change the range references to fit your data.

[image]

Comment: Wow, you are actually incredible. Thank you for the help. Workls a treat!